# Reconstructing sequence $S$ from sequence $A$ which has recurrence relation $A_i = S_{S_i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Lets say you have a sequence of numbers $S$, for example:

$1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 7, 3, 10, 5, 4$

and create a new sequence $A$ such that $A_i = S_{S_i}$ where $S_1$ and $A_1$ denote the first elements of $S$ and $A$ respectively.

For the given example above, $A$ is:

$1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5$.

Given the sequence $A$ is it possible to reconstruct a sequence $X$ that satisfies the criteria used to generate $A$? If so, how would you go about doing it? Is the reconstructed sequence unique, and will it be equal to $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not have uniqueness: If $S$ is any involutory permutation of $\mathbb N$, then $A$ is the identity.

We do not have existence: Consider $A_i=\begin{cases}3-i&i\le 2\\i&i\ge 3\end{cases}$ and assume there is a suitable $S$.
Since $A$ contains a cycle $1\to 2\to 1$ of length $2$, $S$ contains a cycle $1\to a\to 2\to b\to 1$ of length $4$. But then $A_a=b$ and $A_b=a$, so $A$ has another $a\to b\to a$ of length $2$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how to establish that such a sequence exists, but here are two sequences other than $S$ that also generate $A$, which shows that it isn't unique:
$$
1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 6 \\
1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 4, 6
$$